# Facebook App Link Hosting API setup

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/hosting-api#android) to set up a new app link object.  But all of the values I have tried have given me this response:

```
{
  "error": { 
    "message" : "Invalid OAuth access token.",
    "type" : "OAuthException",
    "code" : 190
  }
}
```

What value should I use in the "access_token" field?  I've tried using the "Client Token" from the linked FB app as well as the app ID, but clearly neither of those are correct.  Do I have to make some sort of API request like [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens)?

The documentation is pretty sparse, and doesn't really explain where to get the given values.  I just want to be able to post a deep link on FB to my app, so is there an easier way to do this?

**EDIT:** I found the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), and created a token there.  I tried using that token but that gives me a different error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "message" : "(#200) Permissions error",
    "type" : "OAuthException",
    "code" : 200
  }
}
```

I think I'm getting closer, but I don't know what permissions I am supposed to use when creating the token.

**EDIT 2:** Okay, the token I created in the first edit was a User Token, whereas I needed an App Token.  I did have to make a request like I originally thought, but now I am getting a third error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "message" : "Error validating application. Cannot get application info due to a system error.",
    "type" : "OAuthException",
    "code" : 190
  }
}
```

So I guess I finally figured it out?  I'm not really sure what to do now, because this seems like something that I can't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm not sure how this happened, but the access token I was using to try to create the app link object was not the same as the one returned from the GraphAPI.  I think I must have copy-pasted something wrong.  Whoops.

I switched it to use the correct values and everything works fine now.

Comment: Could you please provide an Android example on how to create App Link object? thank you